# Can anyone identify this chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, food-identification

A recent date left this for me to find...a surprise gift, how sweet! I'd love to know just how sweet :)

It's 1 3/8 inches, 3.5 cm thick. The larger piece weighs 143 grams or 5 ounces.

It tastes pretty good (but I am definitely no connoisseur) and it's certainly in the semi-sweet/bittersweet range.

I just discovered one more possible hint, WinCo Foods sells chocolate block pieces in their bulk food section, there are WinCos in my date's home state of Idaho. They carry both what they call dark chocolate and bittersweet chocolate.

[image: Chocolate picture 1]

[image: chocolate picture 2]

[image: chocolate picture 3]

[image: chocolate picture 4]

Comment: @Jolenalaska : Was it wrapped in any polythene or packed in a box..

Comment: Neither. It was just in a bag like from the produce section of the supermarket.

Comment: Some shards too, it was obviously cut to order.

Comment: The diamond pattern reminds me of Scharffen Berger, but I'm not sure they sell it that thick.http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3252/2773219942_7efdf87894.jpg

Comment: Where are you from? Is it something that could be from a local shop?

Comment: That was my first thought, but if it's from around here it's from Anchorage. I've called every place I can find, no luck.

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but why don't you ask the person who gave it to you?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - They do indeed make slabs that thick, but they come with deep horizontal scoring and the mountain goat logo without any sort of frame. Not a match, sadly.

Comment: This looks like a slab of [couverture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couverture_chocolate) chocolate, so that is what you can saerch for. I tried a [Google image search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=chocolate+couverture+slab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X) on that, but failed to find the markings. You may have better results because Google localizes search results.

Comment: Can you piece together the logo and add an extra pic?

Comment: Do you have an idea what the entire block would weigh? That also helps searching.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This Chocolate is Van-Leer semi sweet. It was an old American chocolate manufacturer that was recently purchased by Callebaut. It does have a distinct slab style. This is available in the bulk section at Winco.

Here's a picture:

[image: chocolate bar]

You can also order it online [here](http://www.weavernut.com/Van-Leer-Breda-Semi-Sweet-Dark-Chocolate-53-Cacao-CHD-BL-6170501-033_p_4563.html)

Comment: After all these years - Thank you!! I'm accepting this, which should be worth a badge for you but apparently isn't. Oh well, welcome to Seasoned Advice and here's 750 bonus rep points on your very first answer! That's hugely rare on Stack Exchange, so I hope you register and keep on posting. Take a look around, this is a very interesting corner of the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

The thickness of the shards makes me think it's from a Trader [Joe's PoundPlus slab](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_GYEen-QNBAU/TUXoBPW3beI/AAAAAAAAKqs/0PMdufwqMGo/s1600/205885.jpeg). Unfortunately, I don't have one around to check if the marks match.

Comment: I'm not sure - the markings don't seem to match this image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_hKTWzHgcNrs/TOM-bEIlMjI/AAAAAAAAAEc/O51o1z6pC6k/s320/TraderJoes72DarkChocolateBar.jpg

Comment: Good call ... I remember the Trader Joe's slab looking different. My next guess: Grenada Chocolate Company. The pattern here could be the bottom left corner of the logo; here's a thinner version of it: http://www.chocablog.com/reviews/grenada-chocolate-company-82/

Answer (score 2):

This might sound crazy but aside from TJ's and Whole Foods, try Pier 1. Once upon a time I bought gigantic shards of odds-and-ends chocolate there, and the chocolate came from everywhere, as you might expect. Not sure if they still do it, but there's always a chance. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a piece off of a 5-lb block. It does not look like any of the "big guys" that I know of...Peter's, Ambrosia, Callebaut, Sharffen Berger, Merckens, Guittard, Ghirardelli, Valrhona, or Wilbur. I'd say the best bet is to ask the person where they got it, and call the store to see what brand it is. My local Kroger grocery store sells dark chocolate chunks in the "Bulk Food" section along with the oat groats and dried pineapples.